# position: fixed (but when scrolled down to the fixed content)

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has his own module position. I want to make the position fixed when scrolled to the content, means when you see the fixed content and you scroll on full screen the content automaticly fixes on the side. But when you scroll again to the top the fixed content will be gone. How should I make the css? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try jQuery Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). I don't think you can achieve this with CSS alone because you are changing its behavior based upon user interaction. You'll need some Javascript.

Comment: I am not very good at programming I only know some basic css and html functions. I also use a Joomla template and I don't know how to configure it correctly :(

Comment: @user2852487, the link I sent you offers an explanation how to use the plugin. You'll have to follow those instructions and you will probably struggle a bit with it. Such is the nature of learning new techniques. If you want to do what you're describing, it's really the only way.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://www.phonedevelop.net/2013/03/code-float-left-right-advertising.html#.UkCwd4YW174
add your fixed menu in that code and content in your html page